# Reference for invalid characters in Resource String Names? Is a ":" allowed?

Tags: .net, invalid-characters, resourcestring

I did a quick check on MSDN followed by a quick search here but I did not find anything definitively stating what characters are/are not allowed in .net resource string names. Currently I am trying to find out if a ":" is allowed, but I would prefer to find some reference that covers all cases.

Comment: if in doubt, go without.

Comment: If in doubt, why can't I find out?

Comment: you could always try it.

Comment: Well, I have a few files checked out of source control for a very large project with no dependencies set up to run it locally for testing. I assumed it would be much faster just to check online.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Colon is not allowed on resources names. If you try it, you'll get

> The resource name XX:XXX is not a valid identifier

For resources names applies the same rules as for variables. If you inspect the `.designer` file you'll see that for every string resource you defined a property is created so it needs to follow the same naming rules.

Comment: Darren: sorry, fixed the answer, the same applies though.

Comment: No problem - I do appreciate it.